# Setting the mouse cursor for a particular JTable cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable, mouse-cursor, tablecellrenderer

I have a JTable with a set of uneditable cells and I want all the cells in a particular column to have a different mouse cursor displayed whilst the mouse is hovering over them.
I am already using a custom renderer and setting the cursor on the renderer component doesn't seem to work (as it does for tooltips).

It does seem to work for editors.

Is this not possible in JTable when your cell is not being edited or am I missing something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add a MouseMotionListener to the JTable and then on mouseMoved() determine which column it is using JTable's columnAtPoint() and if it's the particular column you are after, setCursor() on the JTable.

Comment: I'll accept the answer because this is what we were doing already and it works.  I was hoping to find something a little nicer though.

Comment: yeah, this is more simpler. :D

Comment: This works well, **except** when the JTable is contained in a panel of a JTabbedPane.  In that case, a Cursor set on the JTable has no effect.  This appears to be a bug in Swing (Java SE 1.6.0_27).

Comment: Is there a way can change the cursor only when it is over the cell *text*?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way of changing the cursor at a particular column in JTable:

```
if(tblExamHistoryAll.columnAtPoint(evt.getPoint())==5)
{
    setCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR); 
}
else
{
    setCursor(0);
}
```

Comment: This is the action to change the cursor, but it doesn't include the code about when to perform this action.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to only change the cursor when the mouse was over the *text* in the cell. This was my solution:

```
private JTable table = ...;

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    Point point = e.getPoint();

    int column = table.columnAtPoint(point);
    int row = table.rowAtPoint(point);

    Component component = table.getCellRenderer(row, column).getTableCellRendererComponent(table,
            getValueAt(row, column), false, false, row, column);
    Dimension size = component.getPreferredSize();

    Rectangle rectangle = table.getCellRect(row, column, false);
    rectangle.setSize(size);

    if (rectangle.contains(point)) {
        table.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        return;
    }

    table.setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
}
```